# Importing from excel to Database fails at row number 22091

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, import

While importing 30000 records from excel to database, it fails exactly at row number 22091. I'm trying to read  the excel file and store the data in 2 tables(Tips & Tiplots)

Comment: The number of possible causes of failure is too large to count - you'll need to be a lot more specific about the detail of the issue (what exactly you're doing and what exactly the error is).

Comment: No limit beyond the rows in a worksheet. Check for errors (e.g. #N/A, #VALUE!, etc), text where numbers belong, text that is too long to fit the SQL table's field, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing the data?  It could be a data validation issue causing the row failure at that number (it does seem rather random).  Maybe take a smaller subset of the data (from 22000 to 22100) and see if the same error happens?

Without seeing your code its hard to help...

Dom

Comment: Yes I tried Dom. But if i split the excel into 2. It will working fine. (i.e) Separating the records into 15000 each.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server dont have any restriction to export excel.

based on the Excel version your using , the row limit of Excel matters.

in Excel 2010 we have 1048576 row per sheet.

Excel 97 - 65536

In addition I have experienced Memory issue of while importing a large Excel file.

So Please keep in mind that your server performance also play a vital role in this..